# UITableView reloadData doesn't work on tap event

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cocoa-touch, reloaddata

I have a dynamically made popup view with dynamically created elements in it:
[image: The popup UIView]

There is a `UITapGestureRecognizer` added to the "Post" button which is a `UILabel`. Once the "Post" is tapped it takes text from the `UITextView` and submits it to the server in background. After that I am calling:

`[self.tableView reloadData];`

And absolutely nothing happens, I tried many solutions but nothing seems to work, I am obviously missing something here, please advise

**EDIT**
Here is the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

```
- (CustomCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

//reuse the cell from the reuse pool
CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CustomCell"];

//if there are no cells in the reuse pool then create a new cell
if (cell == nil) {

    //get the nib file from the main bundle
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil];

    //choose our cell from the array of nibs
    cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
}

//give the cell's message property a preferred max layout width of 300
cell.message.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = 300.0;

// Configure the cell with the data
[self configureCell:cell forRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

return cell;}
```

And the `configureCell:forRowAtIndexPath:`

```
- (void)configureCell:(CustomCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

if ([cell isKindOfClass:[CustomCell class]]) {

    //get data from the messages array
    NSDictionary *data = [self.messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    //give the colors to the username and the venue
    cell.venue.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:119.0/255.0 green:119.0/255.0 blue:119.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    cell.username.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:51.0/255.0 green:102.0/255.0 blue:153.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    cell.time.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];


    //get the name of the venue
    NSString *venue = [[self.messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"venue"];

    //if the user didn't specify the venue
    if ([venue isEqualToString:@""]) {
        cell.venue.text = @"No Venue Specified"; //use the placeholder
    } else {
        cell.venue.text = venue;    //otherwise use the venue's name
    }

    //post message and the username
    cell.message.text = [data objectForKey:@"message"];
    cell.username.text = [data objectForKey:@"username"];
}}
```

Comment: are you calling `[self.tableView reloadData];` after the completion of background process?

Comment: check the response of webservice & your array contents for tableview

Comment: Maybe you are calling service in background and after response you are reloading data in background. You must have to reload table in mainthread.

Comment: @Akhilrajtr Here is the Parse snippet I use to save in background, it happens in the response for `UITapGestureRecognizer`:

`[messageObject saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        [self.tableView reloadData];
}];`

Comment: @ChintaN-Maddy-Ramani Well if I dispatch asynchronously to the main queue it does nothing too:/

Comment: @poojathorat the server works fine and everything updates in the back-end, it only that `UITableView` doesn't update

Comment: @StepanUlyanin can you tell us what you are doing after reload table. means can you show `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and are you debugging app using break point? after calling reloadData it will immediately calling table delegates.

Comment: If this is a popover how does it communicate back to the tableView? a popover is a different view controller and will need to tell the tableViewController the results of the web response. It won't happen automatically. You need to make your tableViewController the delegate of the popover and then use that reference to pass the results back to the tableViewController.

Comment: It is a subview of the UINavigationController, the TableViewController in this case has methods to control the popup

Answer (score 0):

you must be missing to set `delegate` and `datasource` of your tableview.
In your .h file write `<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>`.
and in your .xib file set `delegate` and `datasource` of your table.

Comment: Well it's a subclass of `UITableViewController` so no need to specify the protocols, but even if I put the protocols in and do: `self.tableView.dataSource = self` and `self.tableView.delegate = self` it doesnt' work anyway

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
[messageObject saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) { 
     //update the table data source array with new messageObject
     //then reload the tableview by
     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
         [self.tableView reloadData]; 
     });
}];
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't reload the table view

Comment: does your tableview datasource array is being updated before reloading? I suspect you are not updating the table data source array with the newly created `messageObject`.

Comment: Well my data source is updated with the data from the server:/ In `viewWillAppear` I have a query to the server for the data and then I assign the data to a property and use the property at `tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, so the answer to your question would be "no" I guess.

Comment: so ideally after saving messageObject to server, you need to add that object to array. then only on reloading the new object will be added or listed in tableview.

Comment: How would you do it? I only used the data source delegates where the cell in being configured.

Answer (score 0):

If you use gesture so plz try this

```
tap.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
```

May be its help you

Answer (score -1):

When you are getting the response of your POST method, write `[self.tableView reloadData];` May be it works.

Comment: Yes, I call `reloadData` after the response from the server is received, does nothing